# How to join under a different WHERE condition?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sum, pivot

[Advise for different title is welcome]

Forgive me, I'm very new to query syntax and I'm struggling to find an answer to the below.

I have a data table detailing stock trades 'tb_trades', positive volumes are buys, negatives are sells:

```
ID | Symbol | Price | Volume | Charges
---+--------+-------+--------+--------
1  | BP     | 300   | +100   | 15
2  | BP     | 310   | +100   | 15
3  | TOT    | 250   | +50    | 20
4  | BP     | 340   | -20    | 10
```

I need a query that returns, for each Symbol, the weighted average BUY price, the volume balance, and the sum of ALL charges, so for the above:

```
Symbol | Avg Price | Volume | Total Charges
-------+-----------+--------+--------------
 BP    | 305       | +180   | 40
 TOT   | 250       | +50    | 20
```

I have achieved the weighted average price with a "buy condition" as below:

```
    SELECT 
        `tb_trades`.`symbol` AS `symbol`,
        (SUM((`tb_trades`.`volume` * `tb_trades`.`price`)) / SUM(`tb_trades`.`volume`)) AS `avg price`,
        SUM(`tb_trades`.`volume`) AS `volume`,
        SUM(`tb_trades`.`charges`) AS `total charges`
    FROM
        `tb_trades`
    WHERE
        (`tb_trades`.`volume` > 0)
    GROUP BY `tb_trades`.`symbol`
```

HOWEVER, this naturally excludes the SELL charges from the Total Charges. How can this multi-conditional behavior be achieved?

Many Thanks!

Comment: What would be the average price, if a symbol has not buys? Zero, null?

Comment: You've a very valid point there. I had only been returning symbols of a positive total volume so I hadn't considered this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you want conditional aggregation:

```
select 
    symbol,
    sum(case when volume > 0 then volume * price end) 
        / sum(case when volume > 0 then volume end) as avg_price,
    sum(volume) as volume,
    sum(charges) as total_charges
from tb_trades
group by symbol
```

The above query uses conditional expressions in the aggregate functions to compute the weighted price for sales.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7522528458e9edfa6a162b83b5535454)**:

```
symbol | avg_price | volume | total_charges
:----- | --------: | -----: | ------------:
BP     |  305.0000 |    180 |            40
TOT    |  250.0000 |     50 |            20
```

Comment: The average_price can be simplified to `sum(case when volume > 0 then volume end) / sum(case when volume > 0 then 1 else 0 end) as avg_price`, but works well anyway. Curious about symbols with not trades, though. +1

Comment: @The Implaler, thinking about it, since in my application symbols cannot be sold without having first been brought, your concerned scenario cannot arise.

Answer (score 0):

I used union function for the same:

```
select symbol,sum(price*volume)/sum(volume) as 'Average Price', sum(Volume) as 'Volume',sum(Charges) as 'Total Charges' from tb_trades where symbol='bp' union select symbol, sum(price*volume)/sum(volume),Volume,Charges  from tb_trades where SYMBOL='TOT' ;
```

Sorry for any inconvenience caused due the way i have written the code... i am new to stack overflow..

Comment: Thank you for you input and welcome to Stackoverflow!

If I could perhaps help you with an important understanding? Questions are most often posted with a reduced, simplified case in order to demonstrate the problem/requirement. An answer should help to solve the generic problem, not the specific example they have given.

For example, yes, your answer produces the same output table, but what if symbol TOT had sell trades? Or indeed if there were 100's of other symbols?

I hope this makes sense?

Comment: @GeorgeKerwood Thanks for the feedback.. I would keep that in mind.